# TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertSlide' of null (line 60, file "Code")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides

Would be grateful for any guidance on how to fix this error. Please see below code  which gives the error,

```
  // Copy a slide from another presentation and inserts it.
  var otherPresentation = SlidesApp.openById('1Fz6YWCyLIdHfDoonz-40qRlmnNCWwROIQjXqYwmRxS8');
  var currentPresentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slide_v1 = otherPresentation.getSlides[0];
  var insertionIndex = 1;
  currentPresentation.insertSlide(insertionIndex, slide_v1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Tanaike and some changes to the code - this has been solved. Please see updated code below.

```
  // Copy a slide from another presentation and inserts it.
  var otherPresentation = SlidesApp.openById('1Fz6YWCyLIdHfDoonz-40qRlmnNCWwROIQjXqYwmRxS8');
  var currentPresentation = SlidesApp.openById(documentId);
  var slide_v1 = otherPresentation.getSlides()[0];
  var insertionIndex = 1;
  currentPresentation.insertSlide(insertionIndex, slide_v1);
```

Using `[0]` has definitely helped after the `getSlides()`

I have removed `.duplicate()` because it creates duplicates on the template.